# COMExcepton occurred trying to create a new instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application

Tags: vb.net, office-interop, word-2013

I am trying to create a word document using visual basic. I have found that this can be done using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` objects.

I have found some tutorials online (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316384) about how to create a word document programmatically.

I have created a simple windows form application. When a button is clicked the word document will be created. I made sure to add the reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in my application.

My problem is that an error keeps getting thrown at this point:

`app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application`

The error is:

`COMException occurred`

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

`Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: ox80080005 (COE_SERVER EXEC FAILURE)).`

I have read that the following needs to be done, so I have made sure that word 2013 is installed on my machine and I have set the target CPU to x64 inside the application's properties.

If anyone has any insight to what I am missing or if I am doing something wrong I would appreciate the help.

**Update:**

I have tested my code on another machine and it works. So the source of this error is not the code.

**Update: Pt. 2**

I've been doing some more research (http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Windows+Operating+System&ProdVer=5.2&EvtID=10010&EvtSrc=DCOM&LCID=1033) and I believe I may be getting closer to the source of the problem. I've gone into the registry and it seems that the local server it is failing to communicate with is pointing to WINWORD.exe which makes sense. What does not make sense is that it is looking for the wrong WINWORD.exe. I am going to try and fix this so it is pointing to the WINWORD.exe for Word 2013 instead of Word 2010.

**Solution**

What ended up fixing my problem was preforming a quick repair on office. I went to control panel, programs and features, selected office, pressed the change button, and selected quick repair. Do not know what caused things to get messed up, but this did fix my problem.

Comment: It tried to start Word but that didn't work out, it immediately failed.  That happens, especially when you debug and stop your program before it completes normally.  That leaves Word running, it doesn't take that long before you have too many copies of it active and the OS cannot create another one.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab to see them and kill them.

Comment: I've opened the task manager, looked inside the processes tab and there are no instances of WinWord.exe running.

Comment: Then you'll have to find another reason why it failed to start.  Reboot machine, look in the event log for any notifications, disable anti-malware, reinstall office, try another machine, that sort of thing.

Comment: I ran my code on another machine and it did work. That makes me think its the computer not the code. I went into the event log and did find an error. It said the server did not register with DCOM within the required timeout. I am trying to do some research on this error now.

Answer (score -1):

Where do you run the code? Is it a Windows service or ASP.NET application?

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

You may find existing threads with the same issue described:

- [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402262/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x80080005-retrieving-the-com-cla)
- [Office Automation in .NET - COMException 80080005](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/office-automation-net-comexception-173541.aspx)
- [Word Automation with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25289335/word-automation-with-asp-net)

Finally, if all the mentioned information is not relevant to your case I'd suggest repairing Office. It looks like something is wrong with its windows registry keys.

Comment: Everything is on my machine. I am trying to generate the document using a windows form application. If I presses the button it will generate the document.

Comment: Try to repair Office. It looks like something is wrong with its windows registry keys.

Comment: That was the first thing I did today and that did the trick. Do not know what could have happened to cause this, but everything is working now. If you move your comment to an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I actually changed it before replying here.